# How to animate drawPath() on jetpack compose canvas

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have drawn a heart using path.cubicTo() method

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)) {
            val path = Path()
            path.moveTo(0f, size.height / 3)

            path.cubicTo(0f, 0f, size.width / 2, 0f, size.width / 2, size.height / 3)
            path.cubicTo(size.width / 2, 0f, size.width, 0f, size.width, size.height / 3)

            path.cubicTo(
                size.width,
                size.height * 2 / 3,
                size.width / 2,
                size.height,
                size.width / 2,
                size.height
            )
            path.cubicTo(
                0f,
                size.height * 2 / 3,
                0f,
                size.height / 2,
                0f,
                size.height / 3
            )
            drawPath(color = Color.Red, path = path, style = Stroke(5f))
        }
```

[The heart I draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylg7D.png)

I want to animate the drawing of the shape, so it looks like this:
[Animated Heart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d87G0.gif),
is it possible to do animations like this on android?

Comment: https://lottiefiles.com/99228-heart2heart implement using lottieanimation dependency

Comment: @Omkar Thank you I'm going to use it for future projects for sure, but now I really want to know if I can implement such animations just by using compose animation api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`PathMeasure`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/PathMeasure) API - [`getSegment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/PathMeasure#getSegment(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path,kotlin.Boolean)) function to get a segment of a Path, at a certain length.

So if you know the length of the `Path` (obtained from `PathMeasure.getLength()`), you can then get a segment of a path passing a fraction of the length to the `getSegment()` API.

For example:

```kotlin
    val drawPathAnimation = remember {
        Animatable(0f)
    }
    val pathMeasure = remember {
        PathMeasure()
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
        drawPathAnimation.animateTo(
            1f,
            animationSpec = tween(2000)
        )
    })
    val animatedPath = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val newPath = Path()
            pathMeasure.setPath(fullGraphPath.value, false)
            // get a segment of the path at the percentage of the animation, to show a drawing on
            // screen animation
            pathMeasure.getSegment(
                0f,
                drawPathAnimation.value * pathMeasure.length, newPath
            )
            newPath
        }
    }
   // draw the path using DrawScope.
```

Once that animation has finished running for the path drawing, you need to animate the scaling up and colour of the heart. You can use
`DrawScope.scale` passing in an animated fraction.

To animate the alpha, there are a few options: you can use `Modifier.graphicsLayer { alpha = animatedValue }`, or you can change the color of the `drawPath()` command and use a color that has an alpha set, example: `Color.Black.copy(alpha = animatedValue)`

For more information on animations in Compose - check out these [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation), or this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yiuxWK74vI) on getting started with drawing in Compose, it also has a video example of animations.

Comment: unfortunately, it is too much complicated. If you could animate heart path as you described way, it would be awesome.

Comment: Nice answer. Is it also possible to animate subpaths of a Path() object? if so, how would you do that?

Comment: This doesn't work if the Path has multiple segments...